# Toolbar and statusbar z order problem

Tags: c++, windows, z-order

I have a problem with the layout of 2 controls on my window.

I have a status bar which is located at the bottom of the window. Now I want to create a toolbar that will be located at the bottom also, but above the status bar. I used the CCS_BOTTOM style but the problem is is that the toolbar goes behind the status bar and becomes barely visible.

How can I make it so the toolbar is located above the statusbar?

Answer (score 1):

You have two options:

- Dont use CCS_BOTTOM and position the toolbar yourself.
- Create a child window that fits itself in the area not occupied by the statusbar and use that as the parent of the toolbar.